# What to do after a failed heroku db:rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, rollback

I'm at the very beginning stages of learning rails using heroku as deployment tool. I ran into a bit of problem today, which is now fixed, but I was wondering if there's a proper/better way to do what I did.

My problem was as follows: I wrote a migration file that created a table with some indices (using add_index). The code would look like this:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :username
      ...
    end
    add_index :users, :username,     :unique => true
  end 

  def self.down
    drop_table(:users)
    remove_index :users, :username
  end 
end
```

`heroku run rake db:migrate` ran fine but `heroku run rake db:rollback` failed <s>because (I assume) `remove_index` was trying to delete an index from a column that had already been erased.</s>

So I then added a `self.down` method to my migration file (removing the indices before dropping the table). Afterwards, `heroku run rake db:migrate` didn't do anything, and `heroku run rake db:rollback` is stuck at the same error as before. Resetting the database or dropping the table didn't work either. I ended up removing the `add_index` lines in my migration before the rollback finally works.

... and unfortunately I no longer have any idea why `db:rollback` failed. The error message was `'index_users_on_username' on table 'users' does not exist'`, so my guess is that I did something stupid like modifying the database or modified the migration file before doing a rollback. Or could it be because I am mixing change and down method in the same migration file?

Anyway, my main question is, if a `db:rollback` fails, what then?

Some options in my head:

1. Fix the migration file until the rollback works
2. Fix the database manually until the rollback works
3. Fix the database manually and ignore the migration completely (dunno how to do this)
   this)
4. ???

Comment: add your migration code to the question please

Comment: I added the code, but I could not write a migration file that replicates the error, so it had nothing to do with `add_index` or `remove_index` as I originally thought. Of course if I drop the table after I do the migration, the rollback fails.